# Git diff patch without /a /b?

Tags: git, diff, patch

i have a local repository and i created a patch.txt (from the **first** to the **last** commit) using the following command:

```
git diff commitid1 commitid2 > patch.txt
```

But if i look at this patch.txt i see 2 directories /a and /b. And all the files are pointed always to 2 different directories (/a and /b)? How come? I have only one local repository

How do i create a patch so without /a and /b only from one directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do what you want

```
$ git diff commitid1 commitid2 --no-prefix > patch.txt
```

See **--no-prefix** over at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: Ok thanks! But why its adding /a and /b anyway? I have only one local repository?

Comment: They are added so you can see which of the 2 is the 'source' and which is the 'destination' of the changes. Read more about it on git-scm documentation link if you wish.

Comment: Ok thanks. I did something this morning to trying get rit of the `/a /b`. But now if i go in my Github client and i look at 'Changes' i see a whole list of changes and files `/b/...` On the command line if i do `git status` i see: `Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        b/` What is this? And how do i role it back?

Comment: And i didn't commit this changes yet because i don't know what it is?

Comment: I don't know. Sounds like that could be a new question